# Identity Custom implementation With Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I'm following [MVC5-Dapper-Identity](https://github.com/rantowork/MVC5-Dapper-Identity) repo to have custom implementation of identity with dapper. my problem was when i registering dependancies to iOC container this example uses Ninject but i'm using Simple Injector. this example registered their dependacies as [below](https://github.com/rantowork/MVC5-Dapper-Identity/blob/master/DapperIdentity/DapperIdentity.Web/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs#L69-L75)

```
kernel.Bind<IConnectionFactory>().To<SqlConnectionFactory>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserLoginStore<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserPasswordStore<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind<IUserSecurityStampStore<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
kernel.Bind(typeof(UserManager<>)).ToSelf();
```

i tried with Simple Injector which generates exception for me

```
container.Register<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
container.Register<IUserStore<User>, UserRepository>();
container.Register<IUserLoginStore<User>, UserRepository>();
container.Register<IUserPasswordStore<User>, UserRepository>();
container.Register<IUserSecurityStampStore<User>, UserRepository>();
container.Register(typeof(UserManager<User>));
```

How to do the above implementation with Simple Injector

**Update**

@Ric .Net Thanks for the answer but your implementation generate this exception

[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation link provided in the exception?

Comment: ohh my bad thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> generates exception for me?

It would be a better to understand question if you provided the message and stacktrace. In this case I think I can answer, although without knowing the exception I can't be sure and only guess...

Your missing the registration for `IConnectionFactory` and the registrations made for Ninject aren't all necessary, at least not from what I see.

As far as I can see from the [linked GitHub repo](https://github.com/rantowork/MVC5-Dapper-Identity/tree/master/DapperIdentity) the only dependency in your application code (the MVC controllers) is `UserManager<User>`.

The object graph thus looks as follows:

```
var accountController = 
    new AccountController(
        new UserManager(
            new UserRepository(
                new SqlConnectionFactory(
                    connectionString))));
```

So you only need registrations for (apart from the Mvc Controllers ofcourse):

- UserManager => UserManager
- IUserStore => UserRepository
- IConnectionFactory => SqlConnectionFactory

The other registrations are not needed at this point.

Looking at the implementation the classes from Dapper.Identity use plain SQL statement and don't have any status. Therefore the lifetime can be `Singleton` for all Dapper.Identity components. For the UserManager, which is part of [Asp.Net Identity](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/), I'm not completely sure if this can be a `Singleton`.

The needed registrations are:

```
var connectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(connectionString);
container.RegisterSingleton<IConnectionFactory>(connectionFactory);
container.RegisterSingleton<IUserStore<User>, UserRepository>();
container.Register<UserManager<User>>();
```

Simple Injector does not have out-of-the-box support for `.WithConstructorArgument` fluent api call, but because the implementation can be a `Singleton` anyway, this is not a problem at all, you just create an instance in the composition root and let Simple Injector store this already made instance.

If you indeed need the other interfaces to be injected somewhere, the way to register this with Simple Injector is explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Please see the updated question

Comment: I think UserManager should be registered as `Lifestyle.Scoped`.